# How to enable vim-latex-suite plugin in markdown?

Tags: vim, latex, markdown, tex, latex-suite

In vim, the latex-suite plugin is for `tex` filetype. I want to apply the convenience of vim latex-suite plugin for `markdown` filetype. How can I do it?

EDIT: I want to use markdown syntax to take notes. But It's not convenient for me to type formula in the markdown file. It will be very convenient If the latex-suite macros/shortcuts can be used in markdown file(with the markdown highlight syntax).

Comment: Did you try `:set ft=markdown.tex`?

Comment: @romainl, It doesn't work.

Comment: What does "convenience" mean? Please be more specific. You certainly don't want to treat markdown files as Latex, because the syntax is different.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, I'm sorry for the vagueness. The question has been edited for better understand.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about editing modes for LaTeX: probably better on tex.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vim I set this

```
 :set ft=tex
 :set syntax=markdown
```

and then I have all the latex-suite macros and shortcuts working, while the syntax highlighting is set to markdown.

Comment: Great idea. Although the formula parts still have no highlights, it's good enough to quickly edit the formula! Thanks very much.